# Should I mess with file permissions in the Jenkins home directory?

Tags: security, jenkins

Looking in /var/lib/jenkins on a relatively fresh install, I notice some file permissions that are, well, scary:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  7285 Apr 29 13:29 config.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  4008 Apr 28 21:04 credentials.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins    64 Apr 28 13:57 secret.key
```

And in /var/lib/jenkins/secrets:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  272 Apr 28 15:08 hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.consoleAnnotator
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   32 Apr 28 15:08 hudson.model.Job.serverCookie
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  272 Apr 28 14:25 hudson.util.Secret
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   32 Apr 28 13:57 jenkins.model.Jenkins.crumbSalt
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   48 Apr 28 14:25 jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty.seed
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  256 Apr 28 13:57 master.key
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  272 Apr 28 13:57 org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.InstanceIdentity.KEY
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins    5 Apr 29 13:29 slave-to-master-security-kill-switch
```

I'm thinking all these files should be set to mode 600 with owner jenkins, but I'm not sure if I'm being paranoid. Is there some reason why the maintainers haven't locked these files down more? Is there some other well-protected master key that makes these files by themselves less valuable?

Comment: Why is group/all-read scary on a CI server to which hopefully only decent admins have access to?

Comment: @GeroldBroser It's more about insulating things. Nginx is running on the same box (doing reverse proxying) and if somebody were to successfully exploit that, the attacker could run something as www-data and that process could read all these files.

Comment: I see. If it is just to publish build results there's the [Build Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Publisher+Plugin) to separate an internal Jenkins from a viewer's Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

The above permissions seems standard across all Jenkins. Changing the permissions have messed up the set up for me in the past.

Comment: What exactly happened? I find these +r persmissions troublesome too and im curious why they are needed

Comment: With 600 which should be the ideal case. I had two kinds of issues 

1. config.xml - the Jenkins wont startup
2. credentials.xml - the jobs using the credentials failed.

I know it is weird as the Jenkins has the appropriate perm. I had faced that with version 1.58. Not sure if that has been fixed

Comment: Interesting, ill look into this.